# What is the value of $|\mathbb U|$, where $\mathbb{U}$ is universal set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb U$ universal set.

$|A-B| = 3$

$|B| = 7$

$|A' \cap B'| = 2$

According to this, what is the value of $|\mathbb U|$?

I know that

$$|A' \cap B'| = |A \cup B|'$$

I'm so confused right now. Can you assist?

Comment: What's the apostrophe applied to a cardinality (as in $\lvert A\cup B\rvert'$)?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Can you be more clear?

Comment: You wrote the aforementioned string and I wanted to know its meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a Venn diagram. There will be four distinct sections. Let $a$ be the number of elements that are only in $A$, $b$ the number of elements that are only in $B$, $c$ the number of elements that are in both $A$ and $B$, and $d$ be the elements that are not in $A$ or in $B$. We want to find $|\mathbb{U}|$, which is just the sum $a+b+c+d$.

Then
\begin{align*}
|A-B|=3 &\implies a=3 \\
|B|=7 &\implies b+c=7 \\
|A'\cap B'| = 2 &\implies d=2
\end{align*}
so that $|\mathbb{U}|=a+(b+c)+d=3+7+2=12$.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer for its first sentence. (Would do the same if that was the only sentence, too.)

Answer (score 0):

First,$$|\mathbb{U} \cap B'|=|B'|=|\mathbb{U}|-|B|=|\mathbb{U}|-7. \tag 1$$

But $\mathbb{U}=A \cup A'$ and $A-B = A \cap B'$. Therefore,
$$|\mathbb{U} \cap B'|=|(A \cup A')\cap B'|=|(A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B')|=|A \cap B')| + |A' \cap B'|=5. \tag 2$$
Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get $|\mathbb{U}|=5+7=12$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

$$|A-B| = 3, |B| = 7 \Rightarrow |A\cup B| = 10$$, 
$$|\mathbb{U}| = |A\cup B| + |A' \cap B'| = 12$$

Answer (score 0):

$A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup B$ and $(A\setminus B)\cap B=\phi$, so $$|A\setminus B|+|B|=|A\cup B|$$. Also $(A^c\cap B^c)=(A\cup B)^c$.So $$|U|=|A\cup B|+|(A\cup B)^c|=|A\setminus B|+|B|+|A^c\cap B^c|=3+7+2=12$$